# Interview : Suggest a data structure which optimizes insertion, deletion and random value generation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Suggest a data structure which can optimize all 3 below operations :

1. Insertion
2. Deletion
3. Return a random value from set of existing values

Assume that you are putting integers/numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dynamic Array + Hashmap = O(1) for all three operations

- Insertion

Append to the tail of Array O(1), and add a value-index pair to Hashmap O(1).

- Deletion

Find the index by the value in Hashmap O(1), delete by the index in array and swap the last element into the slot O(1), and update the value-index pair for the (used-to-be) last element O(1).

- Return random

Generate a random index for the array O(1).

Comment: appending to the end of an array is not o(1)

Comment: @rai.skumar, use Multi-hashmap, i.e. one value to multiple indices.

Answer (score 3):

O(1) in python:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from random import choice

class DataStructure(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = []
        self.locations = defaultdict(list)

    def add(self, val):
        i = len(self.values)
        self.locations[val].append(i)
        self.values.append(val)
        assert self.values[i] == val

    def delete(self, val):
        locations = self.locations[val]
        if locations:
            i = locations.pop()
            self.values[i] = self.values[-1]
            self.values.pop()

    def random(self):
        return choice(self.values)

ds = DataStructure()

ds.add(3)
ds.add(5)
print ds.random()
print ds.random()
print ds.random()
print ds.random()
ds.delete(5)
print ds.random()
ds.delete(3)

"""
5
3
3
5
3
"""
```

[See Time Complexities of List and Dict operations to Confirm](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

( Note pop is O(1) since we pop from the end of the list)

Comment: In delete() I should have raised a key error if locations is empty. Not to matter.

Comment: Also I didn't end up needing to inherit from list ;x

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash table with [open addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Open_addressing). Keep the load factor between α and β by rehashing when necessary. To avoid oscillation, rehash to some value between α and β. Most open hash schemes implementations require the table to be a convenient size, like a power of two or a prime. Typical values of α and β might be 0.25 and 0.75, with the target load factor being 0.5.

Open addressed hash tables are O(1) lookup unless the load factor approaches 1, and exponential resizing is amortized O(1), so insert is amortized O(1). The easiest way to handle delete is lazy-delete: deleted elements are marked as deleted but not removed, so they can be overwritten during an insert. Again, exponential resizing is amortized O(1), and the delete operation itself depends only on a lookup.

Random selection bypasses the hashing mechanism altogether and just takes random stabs into the underlying array until it finds a non-deleted record. Since the load-factor is at least α, the expected number of stabs is at most 1/α, again O(1).